# Can't retrieve Java thread to stop it

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have a simple Java GUI with a start and stop button. I use the start button to run a thread and the stop button to stop it. The thread starts fine but I can't stop it with the stop button. Here is a piece of my code:

This is the class for the graphic interface:

```
public class GridController implements ActionListener {
// Definisco la vista
private final GridView vista;

acqreg  acq;
public GridController(final GridView vista)  {
    this.vista = vista;

} 

@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)  {
  Object src = e.getSource();  
  String ID = null;
  String IP = null;



  if (src == this.vista.startacqButton) {      

        // Reset di tutte le Label di errore
        this.resetLabels();

        // Check degli input sui campi
        if (this.checkAllInputs()) {
            // CONTROLLO CAMPI ANDATO A BUON FINE
            System.out.println("Campi Compilati Correttamente");

            // Inibisco le pressioni successive del bottone start
            this.vista.startacqButton.setEnabled(false);
            // Inibisco la modifica dei campi inseriti sul form
            this.vista.getcbIDphidget().setEnabled(false);
            this.vista.gettfMiscela().setEnabled(false);
            this.vista.gettfLotto().setEnabled(false);
            this.vista.gettfDataop().setEnabled(false);
            // Riattivo lo stop button
            this.vista.stopacqButton.setEnabled(true);

            // POSSO FAR PARTIRE L'ACQUISIZIONE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            try {

                // Recupero la coppia ID Scheda - IP Scheda dal file conf
                BufferedReader phidgetip = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("PhidgetsIP.conf"));
                String riga;
                while ( (riga = phidgetip.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] parts = riga.split("#");
                    String part1 = parts[0];  // ID Phidget
                    String part2 = parts[1]; // IP Phidget


                        if (part1.equals(this.vista.cbIDphidget.getSelectedItem())) {
                            ID = part1;
                            IP = part2;


                            // Creo oggetto per l'acquisizione
                            acq = new acqreg(ID , IP , vista);
                            //Avvio il thread
                            acq.start();

                            }

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GridController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GridController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            // Ho trovato l'ID giusto --> apro il canale di comunicazione



        }else{ 
            System.out.println("Alcuni campi non sono stati compilati correttamente");
                }


  }else if(src == this.vista.stopacqButton ){

            // Inibisco le pressioni successive del bottone stop
            this.vista.stopacqButton.setEnabled(false);
            // Riattivo lo start button
            this.vista.startacqButton.setEnabled(true);
            // Inibisco la modifica dei campi inseriti sul form
            this.vista.getcbIDphidget().setEnabled(true);
            this.vista.gettfMiscela().setEnabled(true);
            this.vista.gettfLotto().setEnabled(true);
            this.vista.gettfDataop().setEnabled(true);
            // Stoppo l'acquisizione

            acq.interrupt();
  }                                                                                            
  }
```

}

... and this is the class that runs the thread "acq".

```
public class acqreg extends Thread {

private final String ID;
private final String IP;
private final GridView vista;



public acqreg(String ID , String IP, GridView vista){
    this.IP=IP;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.vista=vista;

}



 public void run()  {



    stopped=false;


        try{

            //.....do something.....




            //dichiarazione variabili di acquisizione
            final long start = System.nanoTime();     
            int seriale;
            double tempDevice;
            double tempAmbiente;
            long  prg = 1;

                    //Ciclo di acquisizione
                    while (!stopped) { 

                    // ....do the long work....

                    Thread.sleep(1000);




                    }

    }
        }catch(Exception ex){



        }
}

@Override
public void  interrupt() {


 stopped=true;


}
```

I think that the problem is where I define the thread object "acq" (in a try catch block):

```
                           // Creo oggetto per l'acquisizione
                            acq = new acqreg(ID , IP , vista);
                            //Avvio il thread
                            acq.start();
```

because when I try to stop the thread:

```
else if(src == this.vista.stopacqButton ){

        .......some code.........

        // Stoppo l'acquisizione

        acq.interrupt();
```

the interrupt() method doesn't start and the thread continues running! In debug mode I have this error at line "acq.interrupt()":

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Are you sure that acq object has been allocated. If you get a nullpointer exception there, then it means that acq == null. Also please cleanup the code a bit as it is very hard to read atm.

Comment: Besides your NPE, I'd drop the `stopped` variable (which needs to be `volatile` - if not it can actually cause the thread to continue) and simply use the interrupted status as in listing 5 in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the precious comments, I solved the NullPointerException. Problem was in declaration of the acq object that it had to be STATIC. Now the thread works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several problems there:

1) Your code formatting is HORRIBLE... at least use some IDE that does the intendation for you.

2) Your class naming is bad. Please stick to naming conventions. Class names start with a "C"apital letter.

3) Better not use the method name "interrupt()". And even worse, NEVER override this method in a Thread/Runnable class! Unless calling super.interrupt() in there this will cause serious problems!
Because interrupt() is exactly the one thing that can get your sleep() out of suspension.

4) Do at least some basic Exception handling, you should NEVER ignore exception unless you know exactly what you're doing, and then it should be commented!

Here's a little example of how a somewhat decent worker Thread should look like. It takes all the threading-related stuff away from the caller, and grants access only to the startThread() and stopThread() methods. This way nothing can wrongfully interfere from the outside.

```
/**
 * This worker can only run once
 * @author JayC667
 */
public class ProperThreading {

    private final Thread        mThread         = new Thread(() -> runWorkingLoop());   // if you want worker to be able to run multiple times, move initialisation into startThread()
    private volatile boolean    mThreadStarted  = false;
    private volatile boolean    mStopRequested  = false;

    private final long          mLoopSleepTime;

    public ProperThreading(final long pLoopSleepTime /* pass more arguments here, store in members */ ) {
        mLoopSleepTime = pLoopSleepTime;
    }

    public synchronized void startThread() {
        if (mThreadStarted) throw new IllegalStateException("Worker Thread may only be started once and is already running!");
        mThreadStarted = true;
        mThread.start();
    }

    private void runWorkingLoop() {
        while (!mStopRequested /* && other checks */ ) {
            try {
                // do the magic work here
                Thread.sleep(mLoopSleepTime);

            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // do at least some basic handling here, you should NEVER ignore exception unless you know exactly what you're doing, and then it should be commented!
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopThread() {
        if (!mThreadStarted) throw new IllegalStateException("Worker Thread is not even running yet!");
        mStopRequested = true;
        mThread.interrupt();
    }

}
```